# Why do webkit browsers animate randomly?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, jquery-1.9, jquery-cycle2

Recently I noticed a problem with jQuery 1.9+ and Cycle2, only when viewed in a Webkit browser. The tile effect should smoothly transitions left to right:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true" data-cycle-tile-count="12" data-cycle-tile-delay="400" style="overflow: hidden;" data-cycle-fx="tileSlide" data-cycle-speed="600" data-cycle-timeout="3000" data-cycle-easing="linear">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

as you can see in [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad3vA/2/), this randomness is only happening in Chrome, Chromium, Midori... Webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly an answer to why this happens, but I noticed this is no longer a problem in jQuery 1.10.1.